# Does GitLab Enterprise has different templates for creating Issues?

Tags: templates, field, gitlab

Are there separate templates available in GitLab Enterprise for creating project requirements (user stories) and bugs? Or do we need to use the same template as defined for both user stories and bugs? Is there a provision to create custom fields for Issues?

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab can handle different issue templates for US, bugs, etc. 
You can define these templates using `.md` files that you push directly to `.gitlab/issue_templates/`

The full doc is available here : https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/description_templates.md#creating-issue-templates

As of custom fields, it is not possible for now.